# Is it possible to have a degree-$1234567890$ extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Is it possible to have a degree-$1234567890$ extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$?

&

Is it possible to have a degree-$1234567891$ extension of $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$?

Answer (score 2):

Adjoining a root of $x^{2n}-5$ yields a degree $n$ extension over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. May I ask how to prove that the polynomial $x^{2n}-5$ is irreducible over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt5)$?

Comment: Asking this shows that you have not understood much of this. It is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$, that is the whole point.

Comment: May I please ask for some explanation? Why is that the case adjoining a root of $x^{2n}-5$ yields a degree $n$ extension?

Comment: @ButterMath: you should try to prove that yourself.

Comment: @Clayton I understand that applying Eisenstein's criterion with p=5 gives that this polynomial is irreducible over $\Bbb Q$. But why it is true that adjoining a root of that polynomial yields a degree $n$ extension? Is it because $\Bbb Q[x]/<x^{2n}-5>$ is isomorphic  to $\Bbb Q[\sqrt[2n]{5}]$?

Comment: I think you are aware of a formula of how to handle the degrees of a tower of extensions?

Comment: @MooS I do. But to use that formula I need to firstly show that $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[2n]{5}):\Bbb Q]=2n$. And then I can divide that by 2.

Comment: @Moos To show $[\Bbb Q(\sqrt[2n]{5}):\Bbb Q]=2n$ is true. I believe that I should just apply Eisenstein with $p=5$ to show that the polynomial you gave is irreducible.

Comment: Yes, thats exactly what you should do.